# Namespace best practices when dealing with a 3rd party company

Tags: namespaces

Probably down to preference but I was just after some of your thoughts; I have a scenario where I am working with two 3rd party companies (possibly more in the future) and we provide a service for said companies via individual business logic within the same technology.

Would my namespaces be better laid out like this:

```
MyCompany.Technology.OtherCompany1
MyCompany.Technology.OtherCompany2
```

or like this:

```
OtherCompany1.Technology
OtherCompany2.Technology
```

Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former, since it includes a reference to your company.

Comment: Thanks, and while were on the subject of namespaces what do you prefer:

MyCompany.BusinessLogic

Or

MyCompany.Core

Comment: MyCompany.Core sounds better to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say personal preference.

If there is a lot related in Technology I would do it the first way.
If they are completely different the second way might work better.

this might be one for the community wiki

Comment: There is a lot related; essentially the "Technology" is the same process but done a different way.